# Trying to Logging in database using Enterprise library6

Tags: c#, enterprise-library-6

I am able to log in flat file, but not in database.

I am using **enterprise library 6** for logging.

I am not able to log in database.

Please provide some solution

Answer (score 0):

For logging in database you can use open source NLog in which they give many target in which database is one of the target by which you can easily log into database . Have a look on it!

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

http://justinpdavis.blogspot.in/2010/04/logging-to-database-with-nlog.html

OR

If you want to go for Enterprise library6 then have a look in below links

[Database Logging with Enterprise Library 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003389/database-logging-with-enterprise-library-5)

http://techathon.mytechlabs.com/logging-in-database-with-the-microsoft-enterprise-library/